# Twitter Bootstrap : How to close modal dialog only by close icon?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

i want to close modal dialog by only click on cross(close) button.it has not close when clicked outside of the modal. how can i achieve it ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#windowTitleDialog').bind('show', function () {
                document.getElementById ("xlInput").value = document.title;
                });
            });
        function closeDialog () {
            $('#windowTitleDialog').modal('hide'); 
            };
        function okClicked () {
            document.title = document.getElementById ("xlInput").value;
            closeDialog ();
            };
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

no need of any scripting here. If you are using Twitter Bootstrap 3, Just Add

```
data-backdrop="false"
```

Add the attributes like this

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-backdrop="false" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Large modal</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the doc : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage

Extract :

```
$('#myModal').modal(options)
```

*Options :*

> **backdrop :** Includes a modal-backdrop element. Alternatively, specify
>   static for a backdrop which doesn't close the modal on click.
>
> **keyboard :** Closes the modal when escape key is pressed

So just call :

```
$('#myModal').modal(
   {
       backdrop: 'static',
       keyboard: false
  }
);
```